# Freight Matching ML Algorithms

Tags: machine-learning-model, recommender-system

Has anyone worked on Carrier Freight Matching machine learning algorithms for logistics industry (digital freight matching)? If yes i need help to understand what type of algorithms worked best for you? What business and model metrics did you use?

Here I would like to recommend relevant matching loads (shipper) to a carrier (trucking, shipping company)?

Comment: Can you describe the problem in more detail? people unfamiliar with the domain could understand it and recommend approaches.

Comment: Simply put it is like uber for transporting goods or loads from one location to another. A shipper enters details of a load which is to transported or delivered to a specific location in a market place (info like load dimension, type, material, etc,), When a trucking or shipping company (carrier) who has an account in the marketplace logs into their account they get relevant recommendations (loads) matching their truck or ship capacity.

Comment: The use case here it co creatign Ml based matching algorithm which automatically recommends right loads to the carrier as they log in so that the carrier can decide whether to accept of not. Since it is a marketplace one might find millions of open loads available to be picked by someone, Hence right / relevant recommendations are key